# Overwriting some fields within a nested array of a mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of data that needs to be used to overwrite certain fields in a collection named "Players"

The structure of a Player looks like so:

[image]

The array of data that needs to go into documents in the Player collection is being passed into a controller function that looks like this:

```
exports.updateManyStats = (req, res) => {
  console.log("updateManyStats API");
  console.log(req.body.season);
  console.log(req.body.stats);
  Player.updateMany();
};
```

The `console.logs` looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is overwrite the `Players` document fields `goals` , `assists` and `pim` for each person in the array (`email` is unique) where the season is whatever `req.body.season` is. In this case it is 2020-2021. The rest of the fields, like `team`, `jersey`, `_id` need to be left un-altered.

**Question:** What is the best way to do this? The only idea I have is to loop through each player and use $set, but that is not efficient. I feel like it might be possible with `updateMany()`, but not sure how to go about it that way.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 And please use correct terms, a collection has no arrays nor fields. You try to update documents.

Comment: Either you can iterate over the array and update the documents one by one or you have a look at [Bulk Write Operations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)